# I need a hand with an SQL task

Tags: sql

I have been given this SQL code listed below:

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
stdNo       CHAR(5)     PRIMARY KEY,
login       CHAR(10)    UNIQUE  NOT NULL,
lastname    VARCHAR(25),
givenNames  VARCHAR(50),
programCode CHAR(4))
go

CREATE TABLE Course (
courseID    CHAR(8)     PRIMARY KEY,
cName       VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE  NOT NULL,
credits     TINYINT     CHECK (credits BETWEEN 0 AND 200) DEFAULT 20)
go

CREATE TABLE Semester (
semesterID  INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY CHECK (semesterID >= 0),
semester    TINYINT         NOT NULL CHECK(semester BETWEEN 0 AND 4),
year        SMALLINT        NOT NULL CHECK(year BETWEEN 2000 AND 9999),
UNIQUE (semester,year))



go

CREATE TABLE Register (
stdNo       CHAR(5),
courseID    CHAR(8),
semesterID  INTEGER         REFERENCES Semester ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
grade       CHAR(2),
mark        DECIMAL(5,2)    DEFAULT 0.0,
PRIMARY KEY (stdNo, courseID, semesterID),
CONSTRAINT  fkRegisterStd   FOREIGN KEY(stdNo) REFERENCES Student(stdNo) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION,
FOREIGN KEY(courseID) REFERENCES Course(courseID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE NO ACTION)
go


INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('S0001', 'ABI723', 'Ingel', 'Abby Kate', 'BITC');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES ('S0210', 'KWE231', 'Kent', 'Robert', 'BSCS');

INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('INFT2040', 'Database Management', 20);
INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('INFT2132', 'Advance Programming', 20);
INSERT INTO Course VALUES ('INFT4001', 'Project', 20);

INSERT INTO Semester VALUES (1,1, 2014);
INSERT INTO Semester VALUES (2,2, 2014);
INSERT INTO Semester VALUES (3,1, 2007);

INSERT INTO Register VALUES ('S0001', 'INFT2040', 1, 'A', 98.02);
INSERT INTO Register VALUES ('S0001', 'INFT2132', 2, 'B', 80.32);
INSERT INTO Register VALUES ('S0210', 'INFT2132', 2, 'B+', 87.89);
INSERT INTO Register VALUES ('S0210', 'INFT2040', 3, null, null);
```

I am asked to 'Find the student number of students who have registered to the same courses as “Robert Kent”'. How might I be able to go about this? Can somebody please provide an example?

I am aware of the ability to join tables, I just am not sure how to actually, well, complete the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be with a sub select:

```
select cs.givenNames, cs.lastname
  from Register cr
  join Student cs on cr.stdNo = cs.stdNo
  where (cs.givenNames != 'Robert' and cs.lastname != 'Kent')
    and cr.courseID in (
select r.courseID
  from Student s
  join Register r on r.stdNo = s.stdNo
  where givenNames = 'Robert'
    and lastname = 'Kent'
) group by cs.givenNames, cs.lastname;
```

But it could also be done as single join:

```
select cs.givenNames, cs.lastname
  from Student s
  join Register r on r.stdNo = s.stdNo
  join Register cr on cr.courseID = r.courseID
  join Student cs on cr.stdNo = cs.stdNo
  where s.givenNames = 'Robert'
    and s.lastname = 'Kent'
    and s.stdNo != cs.stdNo
  group by cs.givenNames, cs.lastname;
```

I will leave it as an exercise to decide which is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped, I didn't recall the use of 'on' and 'in'. I really appreciate it :-)